# python - setsockopt IP_TOS ignored

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, python-sockets

I want to create a UDP packet using python with a specific DSCP value. I've tried all day to do so but whatever I tried results in an DSCP value of 0 in my WireShark capture.
I tried using Linux and Windows

Here is the code I used to test.

```
import socket

udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 
socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
udp_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_TOS, 184)
udp_socket.bind(("x.x.x.x", 56001))
udp_socket.settimeout(1)

udp_socket.sendto("Test", ("x.x.x.x", 56001))
```

Comment: "Some high-priority levels may require superuser privileges (the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability).", says http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html . . . have you tried running this as root (or with that capability)?

Comment: Yes, I tried running with "sudo python ..." or with the windows cmd as Administrator. But I doesnt matter, I cant even set it to any priority other than default 0

Comment: What if you `getsockopt` after setting the value? Does it seem to "stick"?

Comment: Yes, that outputs the previous value of '184' that I've set

Comment: FWIW, your code works fine here on my ubuntu 16.04.5 box with 4.15 kernel.

Comment: Thats interesting, getting 0 using CentOS with an older kernel and Windows 10

Comment: Works here on Mint 17.3 with a 3.19 kernel

Comment: Quite strange, I think I'll use a raw socket then and create the packet by hand. That resolves my issue on Windows too